# dashboard in SSRS with filters per chart

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Take for example the following dataset

```
Time      | Action | Location
2018-01-01| Kick   | Colombia
2018-01-01| Run    | Spain
```

I would like to create a report in SSRS that has these pie charts

1) Chart showing Action=Kick for all locations. i.e in above example 100% will be Colombia, 0 for Spain

2) 1) Chart showing Action=Run for all locations. i.e in above example 100% will be Spain, 0 for Colombia

To me a SRSS report seems like it points to a dataset and my dataset has @Action as a parameter. However I am unsure how I can manually set the parameter to a value in one chart and another in another chart where both charts are in the same report.

Comment: I can't see that you need parameters at all. This is simply a case of (on your graph) filtering to your action, grouping on your location, and Count your Times. I think you're really over thinking it.

Comment: Although I don't recommend it, you can filter your full dataset in your chart. You really need to go and actually create your chart and poke around in the properties and you'll find it in there. Close stack overflow and go and open the report editor and experiment.